# How to set sameSite cookie none in Magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2, session-cookies, samesite

My project has a weird issue of the session lost while redirecting back from the payment gateway. This happens only in chrome and edge browser but not in Firefox, I know about SameSite issue, but not able to find the configuration for the Magento 2.3 version on the internet.

The answer is available for version 1.9 but 2.3 has different files so not able to understand where to make these changes.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-1-9-2-3-After-successful-Payment-quot-Shopping-Cart-is/td-p/457185/page/4

I am plugin developer for this payment provider and solved the same issue for OpenCart but for Magento I am not getting any help from the internet.

Website is https://kingzhub.com/